# Openlayers 3 & Angular2, map set target doesn't seem to work on Edge

Tags: angular, openlayers-3

I have a main app component where i creates the OpenLayers map object. The map object is central, as most components need a reference to it. Another component where i set map options before the user can view it and finally the map target

So it work well in almost all navigators except Edge/Explorer.

I have made a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/D87K0iKAeQ2pXd06NtRN?p=preview)

1- Create the map with empty target

app.component.ts

> ```
> ngOnInit() {
>     // The main app component creates the OpenLayers map object. The map object
>     // is central, as most components need a reference to it.
>     this.map = this.createMap();
> }
> createMap() {
>     var map = new ol.Map({
>         controls: ([
>             new ol.control.Zoom({zoomInTipLabel: "Agrandir", zoomOutTipLabel: "Réduire"}),
>             new ol.control.FullScreen({tipLabel: "Plein Écran"}),
>             new ol.control.Rotate({tipLabel: "Annuler la rotation"}),
>             new ol.control.Attribution(),
>             new ol.control.ScaleLine(),
>         ]),
>         renderer: 'canvas',
>         view: new ol.View({
>             center: this.config.map.center,
>             zoom: this.config.map.zoom,
>             rotation: this.config.map.rotation
>         })
>     })
>
>     this.mapInitialised = true;
>     return map;
> }
> ```

2- Set the map target

map.component.ts

> ```
> @Input() map:any;
>
> constructor (private elementRef:ElementRef) {}
>
> ngOnInit() {
>   // set map target
>   this.map.setTarget(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
>   this.map.updateSize(); 
> }
> ```